# Countdown Timer function in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, symfony, react-redux

So I made this certain javascript function in Symfony, and sadly, now I have to redo it all in React-Redux, by sending the data from the Symfony backend to the React App. Sadly I'm still a beginner in React and I couldn't make it work.

Here's my problem in details:
I have a list that show all cars that are stopped in my parking lot, each car has a datetime value that shows when that car was parked and another integer value showing how many minutes that car is gonna stay parked.

My function takes the datetime value, converts it to UTC and add the integer value minutes to it, So it gives me the time when the car has to exit the parking lot.

Then It makes another value of the current time: and does this function: endingtime - currentTime.

So I get a list of all the cars with each car having a countdown in front of it.

As i said, now I have to integrate this function in React-Redux:

Here's my code in PHP:
I'd calculate the expiration time in the entity class itself

```
    public function getExpiresAt()
    {
      $parkedAt= $this->getParkedAt();
      $expires = clone $parkedAt;
      $expires->modify('+' . $this->getTime() . ' min');

      return $expires->format('U');
    }
```

After that I create a span that carries that value in the twig

```
    <td>
     <span class="timer" data-expires="{{ car.getExpiresAt() }}"></span>
    </td>
```

and use this function to create the countdown:

```
<script>
    var timers = document.querySelectorAll('.timer')

    function updateTimers () {

      var rightNow = Math.floor((Date.now()/1000)+3600) // in seconds
      timers.forEach(function (timer) {
        var expires = parseInt(timer.dataset.expires) // in seconds

        if (rightNow > expires) {
                    timer.innerText ='expired'

       } else {
          //  console.log('expires',expires,'rightNow',rightNow);
          var seconds = expires - rightNow
          var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60)
          var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60)
          var days = Math.floor(hours/24)
          seconds = ('0' + String(seconds%60)).slice(-2)
          minutes = ('0' + String(minutes%60)).slice(-2)
          hours = ('0' + String(hours%24)).slice(-2)
          timer.innerText = days + 'd ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's'

        }

      })

      setTimeout(function () {
        updateTimers()
      }, 100)

    }

    updateTimers()
  </script>
```

and finally this is my carList.js in my React App:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Message} from "./Message";
import {Spinner} from "./Spinner";

export class CarList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {carList}=this.props;
        console.log(carList);


        if (null === carList){
        return (<Message message="No cars"/>); 
        }

        return (

            <div className="card mb-3 mt-3 shadow-sm">
                { carList.map(car => {
                    return (

                            <div className="card-body border-bottom" key={car.id}>
                                <p className="card-text mb-0">
                                    {car.number}
                                </p>
                                <p className="card-text">
                                    <small className="text-muted">{car.parkedAt}</small>
                                </p>

                                <p>
                                    <span className="timer"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                    );


                })}
            </div>
        )
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume that you will provide the car staying time in car.expires

So, you should calculate the expires countdown in reacts render:

```
{carList.map(car => {
    return (
        <div className="card-body border-bottom" key={car.id}>
            .....
            <p className="card-text">
                <small className="text-muted">Experies in: {this.getExirationTime(car.expires)}</small>
            </p>

            ....
        </div>
    );
})}
```

Then you will declare this getExirationTime method in our CarList class. Aslso you use two react methods (componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate) to schedule the next update of timeres by re-render this component.

```
export class CarList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // Schedule the updates and forcer re-render if we had cars.
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            // this.props should be different each time.
            const { carList } = this.props;

            if (carList !== null && carList.length) {
                this.forceUpdate()
            };
        }, 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    getExirationTime(expireIn) {
        // modified code from your code
        var right  Now = Math.floor((Date.now()/1000)+3600);
        var expires = parseInt(timer.dataset.expires) // in seconds

        if (rightNow > expireIn) {
            return 'expired';
        } else {
            var seconds = expireIn - rightNow
            var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60)
            var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60)
            var days = Math.floor(hours/24)
            seconds = ('0' + String(seconds%60)).slice(-2)
            minutes = ('0' + String(minutes%60)).slice(-2)
            hours = ('0' + String(hours%24)).slice(-2)

            return days + 'd ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's'
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {carList}=this.props;
        console.log(carList);
        ......
```

And that's all. This component will update itself each sec if it will have cars.

Comment: actually I haven't calculated the expires yet, I just have parkedAt and Time which I should convert to UTC and then add to get that value

Comment: You can do this on the backend and then just use it, or send this park time to front-end and calculate that time in getExirationTime() where you will pass it with the parkedAt.
`this.getExirationTime(car.parkedAt, car.time);`
It's on you.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot man. I counts fine, I have a little bug but that's mainly because I didn't convert the expiration date right. I'm fixing it right now.